# Unable to create Azure AD guest user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

When attempting to create a guest user for any other domain, we're receiving null error details with an "Unable to invite user" message. This occurs for @live.com, @gmail.com, @hotmail.com and other custom domains. This happens when done by both Guest Inviter and Global Admin users.

```
{
   "errorCode": "B2BError",
   "localizedErrorDetails": null,
   "operationResults": null,
   "timeStampUtc": "2017-11-16T15:28:56.9250678Z",
   "clientRequestId": "c2912323-c13d-4dac-8928-5054d0d58035",
   "internalTransactionId": "3108b35a-a022-4aa1-8022-0467e68a7475",
   "upn": "~user@domain.com~",
   "tenantId": "~masked~",
   "userObjectId": null
}
```

Comment: Do you mind to share the method how your create a guest user? We need more details to find the cause.

Comment: This occurs with multiple Global Admin accounts, via ARM and PowerShell. At this point, I'm waiting on an escalated support ticket in with MS. But any recommendation is appreciated.

Comment: i have the same with @ gmail.com domain , any idea ? @UMA